# How to keep current time balance in org-mode's clock table

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I currently have my clocktable defined as

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 4 :scope file :tags "RESIM|DOAS|GENIUP|NOIUP" :block 2016 :step week :stepskip0 :emphasize nil
```

The output looks like this:

```
| Headline                 |    Time |       |
|--------------------------+---------+-------|
| *Total time*             | *34:54* |       |
|--------------------------+---------+-------|
| Work for the RESIM group |    3:56 |       |
| \_  Homeoffice           |         |  1:06 |
| Work for the DOAS group  |    7:02 |       |
| \_  Homeoffice           |         |  0:10 |
| General work for IUP     |    0:26 |       |
| \_  Homeoffice           |         |  0:10 |
| Not at IUP               |   23:30 |       |
| \_  Sick leave           |         | 23:30 |
```

I would like to add two columns to this table.

1. The first column should have some string entry in the first row (next to
   *time*), and in the second row (*Total time*) it should show me the hours I
   am supposed to have worked this week until today, i.e., a fixed amount of
   hours (7:10 in my case) multiplied with the number of days since (and
   including) Monday. So if today is Monday, it should read `7:10`, if today is
   Tuesday, it should read `14:20`, and so on.
2. The second new column should again have some string in the *Headline*, and in
   the *Total time* row, it should show the difference (in hours) between the
   total time worked and the time I should have worked (see previous column).
3. As a bonus, a third column could show the sum of all these *Balance* columns
   for the current year.

I'm rather new to Elisp, so have not really any idea how to start - which means
any suggestions are greatly appreciated ;)